# Почему файл закрывается без close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при таком коде у меня выдаёт в консоли файл, только один раз, а после этого файл будто закрывается и выдаётся в терминал пустота?

```
f = open('first.txt', 'r')

print(f.read())

print(f.read())

print(f.readlines())
```

Результат:

```
Hello
Max
Hello
Python


[]
```

Однако если перед каждым принтом снова открывать файл через open, то результат будет нормальным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл остаётся открытым, но после первого чтения курсор указывает на конец файла. Далее Вы пытаетесь читать с конца, поэтому ничего и не получаете.

Переместить курсор обратно в начало можно командой `f.seek(0)`.

***Пример:***

```py
f = open('first.txt')


print(f.read())
f.seek(0)

print(f.read())
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())
f.close()
```

***stdout:***

```py
Hello
Max
Hello
Python

Hello
Max
Hello
Python

['Hello\n', 'Max\n', 'Hello\n', 'Python\n']
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Файл не закрывается пока не выполнишь close() или доступна переменная с этим файлом.

У каждого файла есть курсор, первое чтение переносить курсор к последнему прочитанному байту - в вашем случае к концу файла. Второе и третье чтение у Вас с конца и до конца файла - но там нет новых данных.

Используй `f.seek(0)` чтоб передвинуть курсор в начало и прочитать файл с начала.

Comment: Большое спасибо!